# Getting Read timeout when calling Yodlee API

Tags: yodlee

I'm getting a lot of errors about "Read timed out".

`Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Read timed out`

Is this error on yodlee's servers side?
How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the API is taking more time. You can override by setting 
Java System parameter as `“-Dcom.yodlee.soap.client.read.timeout="time out in milli sec"` without quotes. Please configure it to **60 secs** and see if it resolves.

If you are using CXF, you can control the client timeout by modifying the configuration for the client http-conduit file.

Comment: Where is the parameter being read? I don't think we're using the yodlee soap client. We're using CXF.

Comment: probably http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html will help you to set in CXF.

Comment: Our current settings are connection timeout to 60 secs and the receive timeout to 120 secs. We're still getting this exception.

Comment: David, are you still seeing this problem ?

Comment: Yes, last time it happened was 2013-07-30 at 15:43 UTC